# what make "frec[v1[i]]++" in this code in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i;
int main()
{
   int frec[1000000]={0};
    int v1[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        frec[v1[i]]++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        if(frec[i])
        {
            printf("number %d repeat off %d \n",i, frec[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to make an program how show men frequency of arrays elements in C 
What make  frec[v1[i]]++

Can it be simpler and more explicit?

Comment: The expression `frec[v1[i]]++;` increments the element at `v1[i]`. As `v[]` is an array of values given by the user, it indexes `frec` with this user entered value. Any element remaining zero was not mentioned by the user; any element greater than 1 was mentioned multiple times by the user. I don't think it can be simplified; it is beautiful already.

Comment: An easy solution can be done by sorting the whole array.Then traverse the array from 0 to n-1 to count frequency.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it would've been more beautiful, if it was devoid of undefined behavior. What happens when `v1[i] >= 1,000,000` for some `0 <= i < 10`?

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize `count` as 0. Then traverse the array in a linear fashion. For every element that matches with `elm`, just increment `count`.

```
/* C function to count occurrences of an element in an unsorted array */ 

int frequency(int array[], int array_size, int elm) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) 
       if (array[i] == elm)  
          count++; 
    return count; 
}
```

If your array is sorted you can optimize it to work in `O(Log n)` time using [`Binary Searchè](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/).

Answer (score 0):

It simply counts the number of occurrences of whole characters in a given string literal. For the sake of simplicity you can think it as,

```
char const * v1 = "tester";
...
v1[0] holds 't'
v1[1] holds 'e'
v1[2] holds 's'
v1[3] holds 't'
v1[4] holds 'e'
v1[5] holds 'r'
```

When you say `frec[ v1[i] ]++;` for each character, `frec[ 't' ]` and `frec[ 'e' ]` hold value of `2`, others' is `1`.
It's exactly what the code does.